# div is overlaying full-screen video in iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe, video, fullscreen

I have an iframe video on a page of my site: [link to page](http://icgworldwide.netai.net/about/) (wait for the animation to finish and the video shows up, ~30sec animation...and theres a good chance the server's down, picked the worst free host ever).
The problem I'm running into is that when I go fullscreen, I have a div that overlays over the video `(.team_container < .team_row [code at bottom]);` when going full-screen on the video, the container stays sitting on top of the video. I've tried setting the z-index of the video container to 2147483647 but to no avail.
The only solution that kind of worked was setting the `z-index` of the overlaying `div (.team_container)` to -1 but it made the links in that div unclickable.

Is there a way to change the `z-index` only when the video is fullscreen?

The funny thing is when searching this, it seems like people are trying to do what I've accomplished without meaning too. I've only seen one other question similar to this but the solution does not work.

The css code for the video container holds both a text animation and the video, with the video appearing at the end of the animation:

```
.underlay_container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.underlay_row {
  display: block;
  width: 960px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.scroll_container {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  width: 960px;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(217, 217, 217, 0.9);
  -webkit-animation: toback 1s linear 20s 1;
  -moz-animation: toback 1s linear 20s 1;
  -o-animation: toback 1s linear 20s 1;
  animation: toback 1s linear 20s 1;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.video_underlay {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  width: 960px;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 2147483647;
  -webkit-animation: tofront 1s linear 20s 1 fowards;
  -moz-animation: tofront 1s linear 20s 1 forwards;
  -o-animation: tofront 1s linear 20s 1;
  animation: tofront 1s linear 20s 1 forwards;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
.video_underlay iframe {
  posiition: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 960px;
  height: 500px;
  z-index: 2147483647;
}
```

The css for the div showing above the fullscreen video:

```
.team_container{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.team_row {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 960px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add any css property to element that is in full screen by using :fullscreen pseudo class: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:fullscreen